# GParted doesn't find partition in encrypted drive

Tags: gparted

I need to make my partition bigger, but when I launch GParted to do so it only detects two partitions. One holding the Grub, and one just being my main 1TB hard-drive.

However, in my Dolphin file manager you see I have another 9.3 GiB partition. That one needs to be expanded otherwise I won't be able to install things anymore. But GParted doesn't find it.

I hope it ain't a problem the partition is encrypted?

[image]

Comment: Aren't those logical volumes and not partitions? The normal setup with full disk encryption is to have one LUKS-encrypted partition holding an LVM physical disk holding an LVM volume group holding one or more logical volumes.

Comment: That's possible. How to make it bigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The following assumes that your distribution uses `sudo` to run commands as the superuser; if that's not the case, then become superuser with `su -` and omit the `sudo`.)

1. Boot from the installation media.
2. Start a live session.
3. Open a terminal.
4. Open the encrypted partition using [`cryptsetup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/cryptsetup.8.html):

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt
   ```
5. Check that the logical volumes have been autodiscovered using [`lvs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/lvs.8.html):

   ```
   sudo lvs -o full_name,size
   ```

   If they have not been autodiscovered force a LVM rescan with [`vgchange`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/vgchange.8.html):

   ```
   sudo vgchange -aay
   ```
6. Examine the size of the LVM physical volume with [`pvs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/pvs.8.html):

   ```
   sudo pvs
   ```
7. If there is no free space, then extend the physical volume to cover the partition with

   ```
   sudo pvresize /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt
   ```
8. Examine the size of the logical volumes with

   ```
   sudo lvs -o full_name,size
   ```
9. You can now resize individual LVM logical volumes using [`lvresize`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/lvresize.8.html).

   `sudo lvresize --resizefs --size` ‹size› ‹logicalvolume›

   - ‹size› is in MiB by default; use *n*`G` for GiB; see the manual page for details.
   - ‹logicalvolume› is the name as given by `lvs -o fullname`.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment GParted does not support LUKS/LVM. I saw some support is being added right now for some LUKS operations, but in any case LVM will take much more time.

You can use KDE Partition Manager 3.0 which supports both LUKS and LVM. If your distribution does not yet offer this version then you can get it from some live CD, e.g. KDE Neon (note that you still need to install it there using `apt install partitionmanager` or via Discover frontend).

Then resizing itself in the GUI should be quite straightforward. Just note that you need to unlock encrypted volume before you can resize it (since underlying file system have to be resized too). Unlocking can be done either from withing KDE Partition Manager or via any other means, e.g. file manager or cryptsetup...